# Minecraft scoreboard calculations with offline players

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to build a ranking system for teams on my server using only vanilla commands (i.e. `/team`, `/scoreboard`, etc). I have multiple mini games that will have a scoreboard objective to track the score that each players has earned in that mini game. I have created a fake player to track each team's total score in each mini game using:

`/scoreboard players operation Team1 game1 += @a[team=Team1] game1`

Team1 is the fake player and also the name of a real team. game1 is an objective for a minigame.

Before this, I set the fake player's score to 0. I run the commands on a hopper clock every few minutes. It works great, however I just noticed once I got someone else on to test, once they leave the server, their score is no longer added to the total even though their individual score still shows up in the sidebar scoreboard display.

Is there a way to keep their scores calculated when they are offline? Maybe some way to make another fake player that holds scores for offline players? Basically what I need it to do is

`*[team=Team1]`

but that isn't an option.

Comment: I have a sugestion that should work. Have two scoreboards for score, one for individual scores and one for delta individual scores. What i mean by delta is, any change in the individual score is also sent to the delta score (If your score is 3 and you set it to 5, send +2 to delta. If you add 3, you send +3 to delta). Then, every so often, you get the sum of the delta scores, add it to the total score (dont reset the total to 0 beforehand), and then set all delta scores to 0.

Comment: @BunnyMerz well I still can't get the delta scores if they are offline. Maybe I just have the score recalculate more often so it is unlikely that someone earns a point and logs off before a recalculate. I had planned to do it every minute so there would be less lag but I actually haven't tested to see if it causes any lag, so a quick timer might be fine. Maybe even just use a repeating command block to drive it. Even if they do manage to log out before it recalculates, it should still be there when they log in next so it'll add it up then and only be a few points at the most. Let me go test

Comment: That worked beautifully, thanks @BunnyMerz

Comment: Nice! Yes, the idea was to make it more often, and don't worry about lag, as these instructions should be light enough to not make a difference.